How can I integrate a custom video decoder into Mozilla?
I'm working on integrating a custom video decoder on an Android device and would like to do so through the Mozilla browser. To accomplish this, I need to understand how the source code is built for Android and which libraries are involved in the video decoding process, particularly within the Gecko layout engine.
I've found a lot of different functions for video decoding in the source code of Mozilla. My problem is now to understand which one is used for Android device, and for what. I would like to understand the decoding process and to be able to add my decoder to the project.
Can someone help me understand how video decoding works in Mozilla, specifically within the context of Gecko on Android? Any resources or insights into the relevant source code and libraries would be greatly appreciated.

I've been trying to trace the function calls of the decoder starting from GeckoSession, but I realized that GeckoSession is primarily an API for interacting with session events and not directly with the decoder itself.
I'm having a hard time finding the functions responsible for video decoding. The project's hierarchy isn't very clear to me. For example, I found files related to Android decoding, like ExoPlayer, in the "mobile/android/" directory, but I can't see how they connect to the rest of the code. I've also come across other decoders in the "dom/media/platforms/" directory.
Additionally, I'm not sure if external libraries like ffmpeg, which are part of the project, can be built and used on an Android device. I'm not very experienced in this area and might be missing something obvious. I really hope someone can help me.
